# Symfony form - how to add some logic while validating

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form, used for a course subscription, in which I have 2 entity fields, activite and etudiant. I would like NOT to validate this form IF the trainer i already booked (information that i can find in the DB through the entity activite). 
How (where...) can i add some logic instructions to control the validation of this form?
Is anybody has an idea? A lead? It would be so simple WITHOUT Symfony (for me)!...
Thanks

```
class InscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('activiteId', 'entity',
                array('label'=>'Activité',
                'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),
                'class'=>'AssoFranceRussie\MainBundle\Entity\Activite',
                'property'=>'nomEtNiveauEtJour',
                ))
            ->add('etudiantId', 'entity',array('label'=>'Etudiant',
                'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),
                'class'=>'AssoFranceRussie\MainBundle\Entity\Etudiant',
                'property'=>'NomEtPrenom',
                ))
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own constraints and validators by extending the Symfony validation classes.

You need to extend `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint` to define the constraint and `Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator` to define the validation code.

There are probably other ways to do this as well, but this gives you complete control of the validation.

Comment: worth mentioning here that constraints can be applied to a whole entity. You can construct the constraint with your entity manager and place your logic in that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You could do what you want in this way:

1- You need a variable to store the EntityManager in your InscriptionType class:

```
protected $em;

public function __construct($em) {
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

2- Pass the entity manager to the FormType class from your controller as below:

```
new InscriptionType( $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() );
```

3- Add the logic what you want in the setDefaultOptions function to specify the validation_groups what you want for the form:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $p = $this->em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity')->find(1);

    if($p){
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity',
        'validation_groups' => array('myValidation1'),
        'translation_domain'=>'custom'
      ));
    }
    else{
      $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'YourBundle\Entity\YourEntity',
        'validation_groups' => array('myValidation2'),
        'translation_domain'=>'custom'
      ));
    }

}
```

4- In your entity, you need to specify the validation groups for the fields of the entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"myValidation1"})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var date
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="start", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"myValidation1", "myValidation2"})     
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
private $start;
```

In this case, the field 'start' would be validated in both cases, but the first only with the myValidation1 is the group to be validated.

In this way, you could control which fields you want to validate.

Comment: I understand that your answer could help in case of restrictions on fields, but i need to do something else : request the database to check if the trainer is available. I don't have this information directly with the entities mentioned here, but from another entity. So i need to make a DB request at some point, and I wonder where I can do that in the form builder process. Thank you very much.